# using declaration in header files

Tags: file, header, declaration, using

I've been looking for some clarification for the usage of the *using-declarations* in header files (I was searching around but couldn't quite get the answer I'm looking for). What I my research concluded so far is, using them in the *non-global* scope is ok, while namespace directives are bad. That I understood (At least I hope so :)).

So in my example I use `shared_ptr`s, but I need to support older compilers that do not have them in the `std::` namespace but in `std::tr1::` for example. Since every class using the `shared_ptr` needs the same `shared_ptr` defition, I would have to put the correct `#include` directive and using declaration in each of these header files. So I moved this part into a seperate header file so I have only one single file where I need to make changes. The decision on which `shared_ptr` to use, is made via a preprocessor directive `HAS_SHAREDPOINTER`, which is set if the user has a compiler that supports `std::shared_ptr`.

**SharedPtr.h**:

```
#ifndef SHAREDPTR_H_
#define SHAREDPTR_H_

#ifdef HAS_SHAREDPOINTER
#include <memory>
using std::shared_ptr;
#else
#include <tr1/memory>
using std::tr1::shared_ptr;
#endif

#endif /* SHAREDPTR_H_ */
```

Now in every header file that uses the shared_ptr, I include this header file. For example in

**ModelPar.h**:

```
#ifndef MODELPAR_H_
#define MODELPAR_H_

#include <string>
#include <set>

#include "SharedPtr.h"

class ModelPar {
  private:
    std::set<shared_ptr<ModelPar> > connections;
  ...
};

#endif /* MODELPAR_H_ */
```

Now I think the way I did it is wrong, since the user that includes any of my header file (using the `shared_ptr`s) also has the corresponding **using declaration** in his code. And that's the bad thing, as the user is not aware of this... etc. So I put my using declarations in the global scope. Or? I'm kind of stuck and confused on how to do this properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found "the" answer myself. I guess that I was not aware that the using declaration in a namespace is still valid in below namespace scopes with the same name. Now Bjarne's words also makes more sense, that one should not pollute the global namespace :). Please correct me though, if I'm still doing something wrong.

**SharedPtr.h:**

```
#ifndef SHAREDPTR_H_
#define SHAREDPTR_H_

#ifdef HAS_SHAREDPOINTER
#include <memory>
namespace blub {
using std::shared_ptr;
}
#else
#include <tr1/memory>
namespace blub {
using std::tr1::shared_ptr;
}
#endif

#endif /* SHAREDPTR_H_ */
```

**ModelPar.h:**

```
#ifndef MODELPAR_H_
#define MODELPAR_H_

#include <string>
#include <set>

#include "SharedPtr.h"

namespace blub {

  class ModelPar {
  private:
    std::set<shared_ptr<ModelPar> > connections;
    ...
  };
}

#endif /* MODELPAR_H_ */
```

Comment: Maybe a matter of stylistic preference, but.... It's unnecessary, and less intuitive, to define everything that ever uses your conditional `shared_ptr` within `namespace blub`. And think how often it's advantageous to declare type aliases in `struct`s (e.g. for use in templates), which can't be reopened for definitions as a shortcut to typenames. So, as far as I can tell, a more idiomatic way to do this is to qualify all uses of the alias with the `namespace` or `class` that contains it: `struct MyTypes { using shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr; }; /*...*/ std::set< MyTypes::shared_ptr<ModelPar> >`

Answer (score 0):

I personally do no see any benefit from having 'using' on any header. **Ever**.

Not only does it make it extremely hard to re-factor since the compiler errors will become useless if you remove a header header include chain. Getting 300+ errors of missed declarations, types undefined, etc; is not exactly my definition of 'funtimes'.

Sure, you can use some preprocessor magic to to get it done regardless of name collisions. But why? If you have namespace collisions there is problem with your approach, bypass that in that way is as good as turning the fire alarm off and claim there is no fire anymore.

As an extra bonus, it also obscure the ancestry of your class a la "Was I using FooClass from the X namespace? Or was it from Y?".

Comment: Hi Manuel, hmmm I see your point and agree that it doesn't make sense to put it in a header file, but merely in the source files. And usually that is what I do, but how could I solve this problem otherwise? Unfortunately I cannot require c++11 for the project so I have to adapt....

Comment: In your headers you need to use the full declaration of the class you are using. Like `std::set<std::tr1::shared_ptr<ModelPar>> connections;`.
Looks like what you want is a single location to manage which implementation you are using; for that you can wrap the shared pointer with a wrapper, so using it looks like `std::set<stdwrapper::my_shared_ptr<ModelPar>> connections;`