# Is it ok to put "using std::swap;" in a header?

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

I've read that when you're `swap`ing things in c++, you should always `using std::swap;`, then call `swap` unqualified, so it automatically picks the `std::` ones for `std::` and builtin types, your custom one for custom types, and the templated `std::` one for everything else.

So, can I just put `using std::swap;` in the header that every file includes and not have to worry about it?

I understand that avoiding `using` in a header is common practice. However, is there a problem with it in this particular case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using declaration in header files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201937/using-declaration-in-header-files)

Comment: @aruisdante No, it isn't. OP is asking about one particular usage.

Comment: @Pradhan one particular usage does not make polluting the global namespace with `using` any more valid, I would think.

Comment: @aruisdante It *might*, if it is true that calling `swap` without introducing `std::swap` into the current scope is almost always an error. That is what OP is effectively asking. So that makes the other question not a duplicate. Please note that I am not expressing an opinion about the practice - just pointing out that there might be a more a slightly more nuanced answer to this question.

Comment: You can use it in a header file, as long as you use it inside a function, in a header file, so that its scope is limited to that function. This is a common practice. You should *not* put it at file scope in a header file.

Comment: I wonder if it will work to create your own superswap function which wraps this for you, and use superswap in all your code instead.

Answer (score 7):

The guidance for swap is to `using std::swap` *at the most local scope possible*. For certain, one in a header file that's widely included does not meet this requirement. It *still* pollutes the global namespace in unexpected ways (someone not expecting `std::swap` will be imported to the global namespace) and should be avoided just like `using namespace`.

Comment: What unexpected behavior could I get?

Answer (score 0):

The principle issue here is that you are assuming that people did not write their own `swap`s that happen to be better matches that do subtly or completely different things to the semantics of `std::swap` and related friends. For a simple example, consider

```
void swap(int* a, int* b);
```

where the contents of the pointers are swapped. Now try to swap a pair of `int*`. You might think that the pointers are swapped, but instead, surprise! it's the contents that are getting swapped.

Really, the guidance for `swap` is the same as any other- only `using` at the most local scope possible and no earlier and definitely not in a header.

Comment: If someone did write `void swap(int *a, int *b);` and your function did `using std::swap; swap(x, y);` on two pointers to int, then you'd get the same problem (it finds the better match instead of using `std::swap`).  So I think the issue here is that the bogus swap function messes with everything.

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, unqualified lookup stops as soon as the name is found in the local scope; you won't pickup the bogus swap declared outside. And there's no ADL, either.